# How to improve the Canvas image quality when client zooms in the page?

Tags: html, bitmap, html5-canvas

I know the HTML5 Canvas adopts Bitmap technology and has its own limitation on image quality when zooming in.

But is there any solution for keeping image quality if client zooms in the page by using zoom function of the browser (for example on chrome, customer use Ctrl + Mouse scroll)?

Comment: Can you post an example image you're having problems with? And what zoom level do you notice image quality loss?

Comment: You could try any example of Canvas, here is an one http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_text2. Then when you zoom to make thing bigger, you will see the broken pixels

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force the browser to make your drawings higher resolution by using an over-sized canvas that is proportionally scaled down using CSS:

1. Make the canvas element proportionally bigger than your intended viewport:

   ```
   canvas.width=600;
   canvas.height=300;
   ```
2. Use CSS to **proportionally (important!)** scale the canvas down to the viewport size:

   ```
   canvas{ width:200px; height:100px; }
   ```
3. Use `context.scale` to scale your drawings back up to the intended size:

   ```
   context.scale(3,3);
   ```

Then when the canvas is scaled using the accessibility features (f.ex ctrl+mouseScroll) your drawings will have enough pixel resolution to look acceptable when scaled up.

**Here's a code demo using the W3schools link you site in your comments:**

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_text2

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// scale all drawings back up to intended size
ctx.scale(3,3);
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.strokeText("Hello World",10,50);
```

```css
/* PROPORTIONALLY resize the canvas to the intended viewing size */
canvas{width:200px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<!-- make the canvas over-sized -->
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=600 height=300></canvas>
```